# Can't use 2 different document.getElementById

Tags: jquery

I have 2 buttons, I need to check when they get pressed and I used the following code:

```
document.getElementById('calcolaPreventivo').onclick = function() {
    $(".gommePrev").validate();
},
document.getElementById('inviaMail').onclick = function() {
    $(".thankYou").validate();
}​
```

But I get an error on the } of the second document.getElementById

But if I only use one of them che code works fine (it only checks the first button), do I have a syntax error or what?

Comment: You have a comma separating them - this is invalid as they should be separate statements. Delete the `,`. Also, you have an odd mix of jQuery and native JS. If you're using jQuery to validate them element, you may as well use it to add the click handler too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('calcolaPreventivo').onclick = function() {
$(".gommePrev").validate();
},
document.getElementById('inviaMail').onclick = function() {
    $(".thankYou").validate();
}​
```

You have a coma instead of a semicolon ";"

this is your code fixed:

```
document.getElementById('calcolaPreventivo').onclick = function() {
$(".gommePrev").validate();
}
document.getElementById('inviaMail').onclick = function() {
    $(".thankYou").validate();
}
```

​

Comment: damn i'm stupid. thanks a lot :) will accept as soon as I can